# icCube authorization on a parent child dimension - how to restrict access to upper levels?

Tags: authorization, iccube

This question uses the parent-child schema enclosed [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/dim_parentchild.php).

I want to restrict access for a user on the 'dim (all)' hierarchy to view all the data at a certain level and below, but **not** the data above this member. For example, view 'Europe' and below this level, but I not the parent 'World'.

I managed to make a role that gives access to Europe and below, using the formula:

```
{[dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].[ Level - 1].&amp;[3].descendants}
```

and default member:

```
[dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].[ Level - 1].&amp;[3]
```

and apply to celss = Yes

But using this role, I still can see the World:

```
select [Measures].[value] on 0
, [dim (ALL)].[Hierarchy].allmembers on 1
from [cube]
```

result:
[image]

What do I need to do to 'redefine' the 'root' to 'Europe', if it is possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it's currently not possible with security to convert a sub-tree into a tree. When allowing a member you do it for all ancestors.

In your example, if you allow [Europe] you allow [World]

Comment: Ok, clear. I think I have to solve this in the presentation layer in the dashboards (e.g. [dimension].[hierarchy].defaultmember.descendants. ).